# calculating average of a vector of doubles in java

Tags: java, vector, sum, average

I'm having problems calculating the average of a vector of doubles. This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;
public class MediaVettore {
public static void main ( String [] args ) {
System.out.println("Insert a sequence of double numbers (the program ends when the input is 0,0):");
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner input = new Scanner ( System .in );
Vector < Double > v = new Vector < Double >();
double n;
double sum = 0;
double average;
do {
n = input . nextDouble ();
if(!v.isEmpty()) {
for(int i=0; i<=v.size()-1; i++) {
    sum += v.get(i);
  }
}
  average=sum/v.size();
if (n !=0) v. add (n);
} while (n !=0);
System.out.println("Average = " + average);
System.out.println(v.size());
System.out.println(sum);
}
}
```

It doesn't sum correctly, I don't understand why. Can you give me a little help please? `v.get(i)` should get the wanted double in the right position, isn't it?

---

Edit for who need it:
for-each version of the solution below

```
for(double i : v) {
    sum += i;
}
```

Comment: Smells like an assignment from very old book. Your may approach by collecting the numbers in one loop, and summing in a different loop. `List<Double> inpuNumbers = new ArrayList<>();` ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be putting elements into the vector in a different loop than where you're calculating the average.  Right now you're trying to do both at the same time which is kind of a mess.

```
do {
n = input . nextDouble ();
if (n !=0) v. add (n);
} while (n !=0);
for(int i=0; i<=v.size()-1; i++) {
    sum += v.get(i);
  }
}
average=sum/v.size();
```

...though there are also a couple other things you ought to improve with your code, such as using `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`, which has been deprecated for almost 20 years, and using a for-each loop instead of an awkwardly indexed for loop.

Comment: `i<=v.size()-1;`  Really?

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will search how to use ArrayList. Plus I have to admit that I'm not comfortable using the for-each, but for the people who need it I will add the second solution in the first post:
`for(double i : v) {
    sum += i;
  }`

Comment: @FredK I was trying not to modify the OP's code any more than strictly necessary.

Comment: The professor teach us to solve like this, but if you have a better solution to suggest I will be glad to hear it, just for knowledge :) or, if it's too long to explain it, you could suggest me the argument to study deeper

Comment: This is an old post, but for anyone wondering the same thing as I did, I just learned that `Vector` is not deprecated, just considered obselete. Source: [link](https://www.tjleone.com/3d-animation-with-java-refactoring-9.htm)